# Changing /page.php to /page/

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to change all **http://www.mysite.com/filename.php** files to show as **http://www.mysite.com/filename/** using mod_rewrite, but I seem to be doing something wrong.

Can anyone help out? I'm guessing it's something pretty simple for those that know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ $1/ [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hey there,

Yeah, but that sends the site.com/filename/ to site.com/filename.php, I need one the other way around, is that even possible?

Comment: @Dirge - Oh, I see now... Changed it.

Comment: That's just the job. I've got another rule interfering with it, but if I try that on its own, it works, and hence is correct. :)

Answer (score 1):

An awesome, simple, copy, paste style tutorial
http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite